# Does the presence of an Origin header imply a CORS request

Tags: http-headers, cors, httprequest

Is it safe to assume that an HTTP request with an Origin header is a CORS request?

If not, what is the correct way to distinguish a CORS request from a regular HTTP request originating from, say, an PHP app on an external server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by “CORS request” you mean a *cross-origin* request—i.e. a request using [the CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol)—then no, it isn’t safe to assume  request with an `Origin` header is a cross-origin request.

That’s because, along with requiring browsers to send an `Origin` in all cross-origin requests that use the CORS protocol, [the Fetch spec also requires browsers to send the `Origin` header for all requests whose method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dfnReturnLink-9):

> If the CORS flag is set or *httpRequest*’s method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`, then append `Origin`/*httpRequest*’s origin, serialized and UTF-8 encoded, to *httpRequest*’s header list.

So browsers must also send the `Origin` header for, e.g., all `POST` requests.

The Fetch spec [further states](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#dfnReturnLink-1):

> A **CORS request** is an HTTP request that includes an `Origin` header. It cannot be reliably identified as participating in the CORS protocol as **the `Origin` header is also included for all requests whose method is neither `GET` nor `HEAD`**.

So the spec actually defines **CORS request** to mean “any request that has an `Origin` header“ — *even if that request isn’t cross-origin and so doesn’t use the [the CORS protocol](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-protocol)*.

That may seem like a weird way to define it, but anyway given that, it’s important to remember that anywhere else the spec mentions **CORS request**, it does not necessarily mean a cross-origin request or even “a request participating in the CORS protocol” — because per the above definition from the spec, *a same-origin `POST` request is also a CORS request*.

So, there’s no way from the server side to reliably identify a given request as participating in the CORS protocol. Only the browser sending the request knows—and other than `Origin`, there are no other headers we can assume browsers will always send in CORS-protocol requests.

Comment: In simple term, A resource said to make a CORS HTTP request when it requests a resource from a different domain than the one which the first resource itself serves.